# How to find all file paths in a directory with bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that looks like this:

```
function main() {
  for source in "$@"; do
    sort_imports "${source}"
  done
}

main "$@"
```

Right now if I pass in a file ./myFile.m the script works as expected.

I want to change it to passing in ./myClassPackage and have it find all files and call sort_imports on each of them.

I tried:

```
for source in $(find "$@"); do
    sort_imports "${source}"
  done
```

but when I call it I get an error that I'm passing it a directory.

Comment: Why don't you assign find "$@" to something and analyze what the result is?

Comment: Why not tell `find` to only find files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `find` to enumerate directories, then exclude them:

```
for source in $(find "$@" -not -type d); do
 sort_imports "${source}"
done
```

Comment: To limit to *file* instead of *everything not a dir*, you can use `find "$@" -type f`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes that's a better solution

Comment: What happens if a filename contains a newline?

Answer (score 3):

Using the output of a command substitution for a `for` loop has pitfalls due to word splitting.  A truly rock-solid solution will use null-byte delimiters to properly handle even files with newlines in their names (which is not common, but valid).

Assuming you only want regular files (and not directories), try this :

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' source; do
  sort_imports "$source"
done < <(find "$@" -type f -print0)
```

The `-print0` option causes `find` to separate entries with null bytes, and the `-d ''` option for `read` allows these to be used as record separators.

Answer (score 2):

You should use find with `-exec`:

```
find "$@" -type f -exec sort_imports "{}" \;
```

For more information see https://www.everythingcli.org/find-exec-vs-find-xargs/